# WIX Setup project error in Windows application

Tags: asp.net, wix, windows

In a project that I am working now, a new WIX setup project was added by a developer. When I'm trying to get the latest from the TFS that we are using for the code base, the newly added project is shown as incompatible and while building the solution following error is thrown: [image: error screenshot]

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Is the file `C:\70_Suite\Accounting\IBS.Accounting.Setup\App.wxs` under source code control in TFS?

Comment: @bradfordrg: yes it is. Hence the issue. Right now I have to exclude this project in order to get things to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a typical team build, the `TfGetSources` activity will do a **Get** to retrieve the source files from TFS source code control.  However the **Get** will set the **Read Only** attribute on all files retrieved, and any attempt to over-write any source code controlled file, during the build, will result in an *Access Denied* error.

Your new project is using the WIX toolset **Heat.exe** utility to generate the file `C:\70_Suite\Accounting\IBS.Accounting.Setup\App.wxs`. This file is under source code control which means it will be read only.  The **Heat.exe** utility is throwing the *Access Denied* error because it can't over-write this file.

One solution is to remove `C:\70_Suite\Accounting\IBS.Accounting.Setup\App.wxs` from team foundation source code control.  It is generated by **heat.exe** anyway, so doesn't need to be fetched by the `TfGetSources` activity.

If you need to keep `C:\70_Suite\Accounting\IBS.Accounting.Setup\App.wxs` under source code control, then a work-around would be to remove the read-only attribute from this file. This could be done in the *Pre-Build Event Command Line* in the new WIX project.

Comment: Great answer, but i was hoping there would be some links/examples for setting up the prebuild event to remove readonly